# Should I delete an answer if it's almost identical to another

Tags: support, answers, duplicate-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I post my answer when it’s very similar to another answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78713/should-i-post-my-answer-when-its-very-similar-to-another-answer)

I posted an answer 1 min later another answer, which is different in the form but basically says the same thing.  Should I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the answers are essentially the same, but with some minor variations, they might reinforce each other. In that case there is a value in having several answers.

If the other answer contains *all* of yours (and then some) in addition to being posted slightly earlier, the value is a lot lower. I would probably delete the late answer in that case.

Comment: Could you watch it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061960/detect-change-in-cocos2d-scene-from-app-delegate/14062008#14062008

Comment: Those answers seem different enough that it could be valuable to have them both. I have seen cases where there are three or more almost identical answers posted simultaneously. That's ok, if there is one obvious answer. (looking for the link).

Comment: Here is one question I might have had in mind, with 8 very similar answers :-)  [C# stored procedure with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201734/c-sharp-stored-procedure-with-parameters). Obviously(?) they are all correct and posted at about the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You don't *have to*.

But if the answer is technically the same, you can delete it out of courtesy.

But in general I do not really delete my answer unless it looks like a complete facsimile of the other.

Answer (score 3):

I usually delete mine if someone beats me to the same answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would **not** delete that answer. Unless the answer is very short and matches very closely the previous answer.

Two answers may seem to be the same except for some details and sometimes those detail matter and make a huge difference for the question author.